# Apache VirtualHosts exception

Tags: linux, unix, apache-http-server

I have following configuration file on my Debian machine:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@domain.tld

    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/workspace/www/%2_%3/%1

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/workspace/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Which is great for automation - i just create a directory in specific path and domain just start working.

But sometimes I need to launch apps, which has docroots somewhere else (typicaly www dir or something else), how do I specify this VirtualHosts and keep working the old automatic VirtualHosts?

When I add e.g. this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.phabricator.com.local
  DocumentRoot /var/workspace/www/phabricator_com/www/webroot

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [L,QSA]

  SetEnv PHABRICATOR_ENV custom/socialbakers
</VirtualHost>
```

It routes all requests on `/var/workspace/www/phabricator_com/www/webroot` and ignores the other vhosts (mentioned above).

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have enabled the directive to allow named virtual hosts. I mean:

> NameVirtualHost *:80

... in your /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file.

Comment: When I add specifically NameVirtualHost, it says:
[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts . So if I change the basic VirtualHost from 127.0.0.1:80 to *:80, it still routes all requests to the first one (www.phabricator.com.local).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have provided the proper name after `ServerName`? I mean, it ends with `.local`; is it what the HTTP request `Host` header contains? If there `Host` header in the HTTP request doesn't match any of the name-based vhosts (or if the request has no `Host` header), the first vhost will be used.